# Getting one slide in my slideshow to stay longer between intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to accomplish is a slideshow that has one slide that lasts 10 seconds-- while all other slides in the slideshow last 4 seconds. In my code below, the current.id==1 condition is my first slide. When the DOM loads, it checks what slide is first, and if it's current.id==1, it makes all transitions 10 seconds. Which isn't exactly what I want. Any suggestions how I could get the all other slides to interval every 4 seconds and still keep my main slide lasting 10 seconds every time it flips back to that slide?

Sorry if that is a bit confusing. Thanks for the help guys!

```
/* Setting auto-advance every 10 seconds for main slide, 4 seconds for all others */

var auto;
if (current.id==1) { //this is the only slide I want lasting 10 seconds.
  auto=setInterval(function(){

    next();

  },10*1000); //10 seconds for MAIN slide
} else { // all other slides should interval every 4 seconds.
  auto=setInterval(function(){
    next();

  },4*1000);//4 seconds each other slide.
}
```

Comment: Show more code please.  I'd like to see how `auto` interacts with your slideshow in order to see how it needs to be modified to do what you're trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write my JS like this.  It makes it far more readable in my opinion and really helps   Though normally I don't include comments like this

Your `next()` function should call itself

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var Page = {};

   Page.slider = (function () {
       return {
           init: function () {
              setTimeout(function () {
                  Page.slider.nextSlide();
              }, 10*1000);
           },
           nextSlide: function () {
              var duration = 4;
              if (Page.slider.isShowingFirst()) {
                  duration = 10;
              }

              //code to handle transitioning slides

              setTimeout(function () {
                  Page.slider.nextSlide();
              }, duration*1000);
           },
           isShowingFirst: function () {
              //return boolean on whether it's showing the first slide or not
           }
       }
   })();

   Page.slider.init();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `setInterval()` if you want a varying interval because you only call it once and then it runs repeatedly with the same interval until you stop it.  You could use `setTimeout()` on each slide like this:

```
if (current.id == 1) { //this is the only slide I want lasting 10 seconds.
    setTimeout(next, 10*1000); //10 seconds for MAIN slide
} else { // all other slides should interval every 4 seconds.
    setTimeout(next, 4*1000);//4 seconds each other slide.
}
```

P.S. You may also want to notice that you don't need an anonymous function for `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` if all you want it to do is call a function you already have defined as in this example.

Comment: Thanks for the response jfriend00!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

```
var auto;
if (current.id==1) { //this is the only slide I want lasting 10 seconds.
    auto=setTimeout(function(){
       next(); 
    },10*1000); //10 seconds for MAIN slide
} else { // all other slides should interval every 4 seconds.
    auto=setTimeout(function(){
       next();
    },4*1000);//4 seconds each other slide.
}
```